# JSon Serialization of a final class into Redis using Jackson ObjectMapper and spring-session

Tags: java, spring, jackson, freemarker, spring-session

I am about to use spring-session for writing the HttpSessions into Redis. I am basically putting maps into the session which should then be written into Redis.

I am using the 
`org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` as Serializer which is setting up the Jackson ObjectMapper with:
`mapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);` but as the setting already states, it doesn't work with anything final (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).

I found out that somewhere in the CMS I am using (HippoCMS) the `FreemarkerServlet` is initialized including the following code:

```
void initializeSessionAndInstallModel(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpSessionHashModel sessionModel, 
            HttpSession session)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        session.setAttribute(ATTR_SESSION_MODEL, sessionModel);
        initializeSession(request, response);
    }
```

Unfortunately the `HttpSessionHashModel` is a final class and is written into the session. The serializer only writes sth. like `{"empty":true}` into Redis which makes it impossible for the Deserializer to deserialize the JSON cause no `@class` attribute is written into the JSon.

**How can I tell the ObjectMapper to add a @class attribute for the final class. If it is not possible, what might be a possible solution for my problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do correctly. If so, Mix-In annotations could address your problem. Have a look [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html).
You basically define Jackson annotations on a interface and set up your ObjectMapper's serialization/deserialization to consider that interface for a specific type.

Good luck!